# Ограчение видимости отдельных сайтов на VDS

Tags: ubuntu, apache

На vds есть несколько сайтов, запуская bash команды из php можно увидеться всю структуру севера и все сайты которые на нем крутятся.
Файловая структура следующая

```
/var/www/example.ru/public_html/index.php
```

Как ограничить права просмотра, что бы выше директории public_html ни чего видно не было?
ОС: Ubuntu 14 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash команды можно ограничить только правильной настройкой прав доступа для юзеров. Для каждого сайта должен быть свой юзер, это можно сделать если настроить apache2-mpm-itk.

Comment: знак "="  у вас в коде лишний.  Но по какой то причине ситуация не изменилась. привожу пример кода, моего файла виртуального хоста
после каждого действия производил перезагрузку апача

    ServerAdmin example@mail.ru 
    ServerName example.ru
    ServerAlias www.example.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.ru/public_html
    php_admin_value open_basedir  "/var/www/example.ru/public_html/"

Comment: @ЛеоКомаров, обновил ответ, open_basedir сделает ограничение только для php скриптов, но не для bash

Comment: я вывожу корень сайта через print_r($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
выводиться путь "/var/www/example.ru/public_html", 
файл находиться в public_html

Comment: если в таком ключе посмотреть, то никак. PHP знает путь к текущему файлу в любом случае, это нельзя ограничить. Непонятно тогда зачем в вопросе упоминание bash скриптов.

Comment: это я привел для примера, по большому счету это тоже самое что и exec('pwd', $output)

Comment: это совсем разные вещи, и результат не всегда одинаков, в $_SERVER можно что угодно записать, а выполнение консольных команд вообще отключить. Так вопрос решен или нет?